# New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, dpkg

This is the details I get when the package operation fails if I click repair:

```
installArchives() failed: E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg: regarding .../libgcc1_1%3a4.9.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb containing libgcc1:amd64, pre-dependency problem:
 libgcc1 pre-depends on multiarch-support
  multiarch-support is unpacked, but has never been configured.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.9.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing libgcc1:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.9.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6:amd64:
 libc6:amd64 depends on libgcc1; however:
  Package libgcc1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of multiarch-support:
 multiarch-support depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-2); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package multiarch-support (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: Try this post from ubuntuforums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947124&s=2ffe34dba1ee40395ad3372134b7775e&p=5962046#post5962046

Comment: Can you append to your question, the output of `apt-cache policy debconf`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried reinstalling deconf:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall deconf
```

and then reinstall this:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall debconf
```

and then this:

```
 sudo dkms--reconfigure debconf
```

and it might work fine this way.